# make a letter "C" print using python the code I currently have is down below but I'm not sure how to add 2 stars to the end

Tags: python

I need to make a letter "C" print using python the code I currently have is down below but I'm not sure how to add 2 stars to the end of the letter. Needed in python.

**Here is my current output:**

```
Enter an odd number 5 or greater: 5

 ***
*
*
*
*
 ***
```

**Here is my needed Output:**

```
Enter an odd number 5 or greater: 5

 ***
*   *
*
*
*   *
 ***
```

**Current Code:**

```
import math
# Purpose: Draw one symbol on either side of the line
#          leaving (width-2) spaces between the symbols
def draw_side(width,symbol,height):
    print(symbol + " "*(width))

# Purpose: Produce a letetr 'A' drawn with the symbol
#          provided using the given width and height
def draw_A(width,height,symbol):
    print(" ")
    mid = math.floor(height/2)
    print(" " + symbol*(width))
    for i in range(1, height):
        if i == mid:
            print(symbol)
        else:
            draw_side(width,symbol,height)
            
            
    print(" " + symbol*(width))
   
# Purpose: Prompt the user for an integer 5 or greater
#          and return valid user input
def get_height():
    height = int(input("Enter an odd number 5 or greater: "))
    while(1):
        if (height % 2)==0 or (height < 5) :
            height = int(input("-> Error! Try again: "))
        else :
            break;
    return height

# Purpose: Calls helper function to get height, and calculates width.
#          Finally calls draw_A() to draw letter 'A' with given symbol
def draw_letter(symbol):
    height = get_height()
    width = height - 2
    draw_A(width,height,symbol)


draw_letter('*')
```

Comment: Please post the output as plain text, not screenshots.

Comment: Why is the function called `draw_A` if it draws `C`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of attempting to modify your current code to work, I would suggest a system like the one below. It uses an dictionary of characters that you define yourself. If you want to replace the symbol programmatically, you could just replace each character in the string when printing.

Unfortunately/fortunately, the code below is actually animated. So you can keep the animation if you like, or just delete that code if you don't want it.

This code was sourced from someone else a LONG time ago for my own school assessment (I forgot where from though), but I have made some improvements to it since then.

```
#----------------------------------------------
# Animated Banner Program
#----------------------------------------------

import os
import time
import sys
repeat=0

//The below warning is only needed if you keep the animation
if 'idlelib.run' in sys.modules:
    input('\nPlease make sure that you have opened the program by double clicking on it\n(Not in IDLE)\tPress enter to start anyway:\t')

#the width of the display
#(the windows console is 79 characters wide).
WIDTH = 115

message="Your Text"

message=message.upper()
#the printed banner version of the message
#this is a 7-line display, stored as 7 strings
#initially, these are empty.
printedMessage = [ "","","","","","","" ]

#a dictionary mapping letters to their 7-line
#banner display equivalents. each letter in the dictionary
#maps to 7 strings, one for each line of the display.
characters = { " " : [ "   ",
                       "   ",
                       "   ",
                       "   ",
                       "   ",
                       "   ",
                       "   " ],

               "A" : [ "*****",
                       "*   *",
                       "*   *",
                       "*****",
                       "*   *",
                       "*   *",
                       "*   *" ],

               "B" : [ "**** ",
                       "*   *",
                       "*   *",
                       "**** ",
                       "*   *",
                       "*   *",
                       "**** " ],

               "C" : [ " ****",
                       "*    ",
                       "*    ",
                       "*    ",
                       "*    ",
                       "*    ",
                       " ****" ],

               "D" : [ "**** ",
                       "*   *",
                       "*   *",
                       "*   *",
                       "*   *",
                       "*   *",
                       "**** " ],

               "E" : [ "*****",
                       "*    ",
                       "*    ",
                       "*****",
                       "*    ",
                       "*    ",
                       "*****" ],

               "F" : [ "*****",
                       "*    ",
                       "*    ",
                       "*****",
                       "*    ",
                       "*    ",
                       "*    " ],

               "G" : [ " *** ",
                       "*   *",
                       "*    ",
                       "*    ",
                       "* ***",
                       "*   *",
                       " *** " ],
               
               "H" : [ "*   *",
                       "*   *",
                       "*   *",
                       "*****",
                       "*   *",
                       "*   *",
                       "*   *" ],

               "I" : [ "*****",
                       "  *  ",
                       "  *  ",
                       "  *  ",
                       "  *  ",
                       "  *  ",
                       "*****" ],

               "J" : [ "******",
                       "    * ",
                       "    * ",
                       "    * ",
                       "    * ",
                       "*   * ",
                       " ***  " ],

               "K" : [ "*   *",
                       "*  * ",
                       "* *  ",
                       "**   ",
                       "* *  ",
                       "*  * ",
                       "*   *" ],

               "L" : [ "*    ",
                       "*    ",
                       "*    ",
                       "*    ",
                       "*    ",
                       "*    ",
                       "*****" ],

               "M" : [ "**       **",
                       "* *     * *",
                       "*  *   *  *",
                       "*   * *   *",
                       "*    *    *",
                       "*    *    *",
                       "*    *    *" ],

               "N" : [ "*     *",
                       "**    *",
                       "* *   *",
                       "*  *  *",
                       "*   * *",
                       "*    **",
                       "*     *" ],

               "O" : [ "*****",
                       "*   *",
                       "*   *",
                       "*   *",
                       "*   *",
                       "*   *",
                       "*****" ],

               "P" : [ "*****",
                       "*   *",
                       "*   *",
                       "*****",
                       "*    ",
                       "*    ",
                       "*    " ],


               "Q" : [ " ***** ",
                       "*     *",
                       "*     *",
                       "*     *",
                       "*   \ *",
                       "*    \ ",
                       " **** \\" ],

               "R" : [ "***** ",
                       "*    *",
                       "*    *",
                       "****  ",
                       "*   * ",
                       "*    *",
                       "*    *" ],

               "S" : [ " ****",
                       "*    ",
                       "*    ",
                       " *** ",
                       "    *",
                       "    *",
                       "**** " ],

               "T" : [ "*******",
                       "   *   ",
                       "   *   ",
                       "   *   ",
                       "   *   ",
                       "   *   ",
                       "   *   " ],

               "U" : [ "*    *",
                       "*    *",
                       "*    *",
                       "*    *",
                       "*    *",
                       "*    *",
                       " **** " ],

               "V" : [ "*   * ",
                       "*   * ",
                       "*   * ",
                       "*   * ",
                       "*   * ",
                       " * *  ",
                       "  *   " ],

               "W" : [ "*        *",
                       "*        *",
                       "*        *",
                       "*   **   *",
                       "*  *  *  *",
                       "* *    * *",
                       "**      **" ],

               "X" : [ "*     *",
                       " *   * ",
                       "  * *  ",
                       "   *   ",
                       "  * *  ",
                       " *   * ",
                       "*     *" ],

               "Y" : [ "*     *",
                       " *   * ",
                       "  * *  ",
                       "   *   ",
                       "   *   ",
                       "   *   ",
                       "   *   " ],

               "Z" : [ "*****",
                       "    *",
                       "   * ",
                       "  *  ",
                       " *   ",
                       "*    ",
                       "*****" ],

               "1" : [ "  *  ",
                       "***  ",
                       "  *  ",
                       "  *  ",
                       "  *  ",
                       "  *  ",
                       "*****" ],

               "2" : [ " *** ",
                       "*   *",
                       "    *",
                       "   * ",
                       " *   ",
                       "*    ",
                       "*****" ],

               "3" : [ " *** ",
                       "*   *",
                       "    *",
                       "   * ",
                       "    *",
                       "*   *",
                       " *** " ],

               "4" : [ "*   *",
                       "*   *",
                       "*   *",
                       "*****",
                       "    *",
                       "    *",
                       "    *" ],

               "5" : [ "*****",
                       "*    ",
                       "*    ",
                       "**** ",
                       "    *",
                       "    *",
                       "**** " ],

               "6" : [ " ****",
                       "*    ",
                       "*    ",
                       "**** ",
                       "*   *",
                       "*   *",
                       " *** " ],

               "7" : [ "******",
                       "     *",
                       "     *",
                       "    * ",
                       "    * ",
                       "   *  ",
                       "   *  " ],

               "8" : [ " *** ",
                       "*   *",
                       " * * ",
                       "  *  ",
                       " * * ",
                       "*   *",
                       " *** " ],

               "9" : [ " *** ",
                       "*   *",
                       "*   *",
                       " ****",
                       "    *",
                       "    *",
                       "    *" ],

               "0" : [ " *** ",
                       "*   *",
                       "*  **",
                       "* * *",
                       "**  *",
                       "*   *",
                       " *** " ],


               "!" : [ "  *  ",
                       "  *  ",
                       "  *  ",
                       "  *  ",
                       "  *  ",
                       "     ",
                       "  *  " ],

               "'" : [ " | ",
                       " | ",
                       "   ",
                       "   ",
                       "   ",
                       "   ",
                       "   " ],

               "." : [ "     ",
                       "     ",
                       "     ",
                       "     ",
                       "     ",
                       "     ",
                       "*    " ],

               "," : [ "  ",
                       "  ",
                       "  ",
                       "  ",
                       "  ",
                       " /",
                       "/ " ]
               
               }

for row in range(7):
    for char in message:
        printedMessage[row] += (str(characters[char][row]) + "  ")

#the offset is how far to the right we want to print the message.
#initially, we want to print the message just off the display.
offset = WIDTH
while True:
    os.system("cls")
    #print each line of the message, including the offset.
    for row in range(7):
        print(" " * offset + printedMessage[row][max(0,offset*-1):WIDTH - offset])
    #move the message a little to the left.
    offset-=1
    #if the entire message has moved 'through' the display then
    #start again from the right hand side.
    if offset <= ((len(message)+2)*6) * -1:
        offset = WIDTH
    #take out or change this line to speed up / slow down the display
    time.sleep(0.00)
```

Comment: Howe does this answer the OPs question?

Comment: It's an alternative solution. If the OP doesn't like it, I'm more than happy to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify `draw_side` to take a argument `end` for what to print at the end of the line:

```
def draw_side(width, symbol, height, end=''):
    print(symbol + " "*(width) + end)
```

Then check if you're at the first or last inner line and send `symbol` as the end value if so. You also don't need `math` module for this just use floor division.

```
def draw_A(width,height,symbol):
    print(" ")
    mid = height // 2
    print(" " + symbol*(width))
    for i in range(1, height):
        if i == 1 or i == height-1:
            draw_side(width, symbol, height, symbol)
        else:
            draw_side(width, symbol, height)
            
            
    print(" " + symbol*(width))
```